# Get struct field name by offset C

Tags: c

I am not sure it is possible, but I am trying to find a way to get the struct's field name by its offset.

Assume I have a simple struct, and macro that uses these fields by name:

```
#define COPY_FIELD(target, source, field) \
    do { \
        (target) = source.field; \
    } while (0)

struct fields {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};
```

**Assuming I can't change the macro**, Is there a way to use it relative to the beginning of the struct: 
Or any other way that will not require me to write the field's name? 
Regular usage example:

```
int return_target() {
    struct fields f;
    int target;
    f.a = 0;
    f.b = 1;
    f.c = 2;
    COPY_FIELD(target, f, c);
    return target;
}
```

What I need (something like that):

```
int return_target(int idx) {
    struct fields f;
    int target;
    COPY_FIELD(target, f, (a + idx));
    return target;
}
```

Of course, the last code will not work because the `source.(a+idx)` is not defined.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your title indicates you want to get a field name, but the code in your question suggests you merely want to access the field, which does not require its name. Please edit the title and the question to clarify. Also edit the question to explain the requirements regarding this `idx`. Does it have to be an index that counts fields (0 for the first field, 1 for the next, and so on)? Or can it be a byte offset from the beginning of the structure?

Comment: You can offset a certain number of bytes into a struct using a `char *`, but not a certain number of fields.  What's the use case for this?  What problem would be solved by having this ability?

Comment: How will the caller obtain this index so they can pass it to `target`—does it have to be built into source code, or can it be obtained by some means during program execution? Are all the structure members to be accessed this way the same type?

Comment: @dbush, I can do it for an allocated struct, but can I do it for a non-allocated struct. The use case is the macro usage constraint. I have a macro used by many different structs and a single struct with a growing list of fields. So I am thinking of an elegant way to implement the macro application on that particular struct.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The argument is not pre-compiled, dynamically determined during run time.

Comment: It sounds like your struct should contain an array, and you would just index that array.

Comment: I think this is an XY question.  *Why* do you want to access structure members by offset rather than by name?  What do you think you will gain by that relative to access by member name?

Comment: it's not clear what you pretend... the macro requires a structure (`source`) and a field (`field`) because it uses them at both sides of a `.` operator.  There's no way to pass parameters to this macro without the third being a field, because after macro expansion, you will get a syntax error.  In old C you could pass two integers as second and third parameter, in order to get a floating point literal.  But today, the C preprocessor gives tokenized input, and you cannot use that macro to build a single floating point literal (and I'm departing a bit from the subject)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to *compute* the field name by its offset, but you can use a `switch` statement to emulate the desired behavior:

```
int return_target(int idx) {
    struct fields f = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int target = -1;
    switch (idx) {
    case 0: COPY_FIELD(target, f, a); break;
    case 1: COPY_FIELD(target, f, b); break;
    case 2: COPY_FIELD(target, f, c); break;
    }
    return target;
}
```

Abusing the rules, you could pretend the structure is an array of `int`, and write this:

```
int return_target(int idx) {
    struct fields f = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int target;
    COPY_FIELD(target, f, a * 0 + idx[(int *)&f]);
    return target;
}
```

`COPY_FIELD(target, f, a * 0 + idx[(int *)&f]);` expands to

```
do { (target) = source.a * 0 + idx[(int *)&f]; } while (0)
```

which sets `target` to the value of `int` located `idx` places from the beginning of the structure.  This only works because all of the fields have the same type `int`.  Note also that the code will have undefined behavior if `idx` is not `0`, `1` or `2`.

Here is a *cleaner* way to do it using an array of offsets:

```
#include <stddef.h>  // for the offsetof macro

struct fields {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};

static size_t field_offsets[] = {
    offsetof(struct fields, a),
    offsetof(struct fields, b),
    offsetof(struct fields, c),
};

int return_target(int idx) {
    struct fields f = { 1, 2, 3 };
    if (idx >= 0 && idx < sizeof(field_offsets) / sizeof(*field_offsets)) {
        return *(int *)((char *)&f + field_offsets[idx]);
    } else {
        // invalid index
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assume that there is a very long list of fields. Is there a way to do it without using a switch-case?

Comment: @ItamarG: indeed you can use an ancillary array to specify the byte offsets of the `int` fields in the structure.  Answer amended.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to obtain the name of a field given an offset. If you want to access the **data** of a field given an offset, just obtain a pointer to the struct as a `char *` pointer (so the pointer arithmetic will be handled in bytes), add the offset, and the cast to the desired type, in this case `int`.

```
int target(int idx) { // idx will have to be an offset in bytes to the desired field
    struct fields f;
    int target = *(int *)((char *)&f+idx);
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Where do you use the macro? I don't need to field offset. I need to use it in a macro. It may not be possible.